# NixOS + Win 10 boot: OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device /boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, nixos

I am using an old laptop with Windows 10 installed. I also wanted to try out NixOS, alongside that windows OS. I also tried installing some packages, tried the nixos-rebuild command then the problem came. The boot partition which came with Windows is 100 MB or so:

[image]

If you see there is another Microsoft partition which reserved for some purpose, so can't increase the size. Did anyone had similar problem? Were you able to solve this problem?

Comment: OSes require different EFI partition sizes and NixOS [requires](https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/#sec-installation-manual-partitioning) 512MB, so resize the EFI partition to at least 627MB [RAW] _(612MB formatted)_ using Gparted on a LiveUSB. Technically the MSR partition (#3) can be deleted entirely, and some OEMs don't configure a drive with that partition, Microsoft does recommend it's created and kept. Delete the MSR partition, shrink partition 4 by 525MB [RAW], resize the EFI partition, then once back in Windows, re-create the MSR partition via `DiskPart`: `cre par msr`

Answer (score 1):

This is not easily resolved, because, as you state, there is a Recovery partition before the Boot partition, and a small 17 MB partition after. **First make a disk image in case something goes wrong in the next steps.** Then, if the 17 MB partition is unused, you might try extending the 104 MB partition into it by perhaps 15 MB. I suggest leaving a buffer of a MB or two, though, between Boot and Windows.

If that provides sufficient room, well and good. If not, you might need to extend the Boot partition *down* into what is now Recovery, a slow process fraught with chance to make the PC unbootable.

Consider making NixOS a virtual machine within Windows 10, using [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) or other VM, such as Oracle's free [VirtualBox (VBox)](https://www.virtualbox.org/)... I found VBox surprisingly fast and easy to use, at the expense of ~40 GB of disk space for the new OS.

Also consider *scrapping* Windows 10 entirely, since support for that OS ends soon. If you have an old PC with little data, unable to move to Win 11, wipe the drive (or let the new OS installation do so. Not sure if NixOS has that option, but Ubuntu gives a choice of installing dual-boot or automatically repartitioning for just Linux), and install the new OS to the full disk.